# Term for street meant for cars and pedestrians

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a term for a street that has no adjoining sidewalk and is instead intended (the street itself) for vehicles and pedestrians to share? Such a thing is called a רחוב הולנדי, literally a Dutch road, in Hebrew, but that term doesn't seem to exist in English; is there some other name for it?

To be clear, I'm asking about any street (or a residential street) designed for cars and pedestrians. Typically, at least in such streets that I'm familiar with, the surface will be different from that of a normal street, so as to call attention to its being meant for pedestrians also (and perhaps to slow cars down). I'm *not* asking about a pedestrian mall, which is meant for pedestrians only even though it otherwise may be just like a street: what I'm thinking of is for vehicles also.

Comment: There may not by anything more specific than 'road'. Holland is more laisez-faire on their pedestrian-vehicular boundaries.

Comment: It's called a really bad idea. Some forms of shared use are fine. Pedestrians and cars is not one of them.

Comment: @PhilSweet Research has shown that it is not a bad idea at all. 'Shared spaces' are gaining ground in the UK. And they are very effective. Gloucester city centre, for example.

Comment: In the US this is hardly ever done (outside of a parking lot), and hence there is no established term.

Answer (score 2):

In English it's *shared space* or *home zone*

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shared_space

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hans_Monderman

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Woonerf

A woonerf is a living street, as originally implemented in the Netherlands and in Flanders, the Dutch-speaking northern portion of Belgium. Techniques include shared space, traffic calming, and low speed limits. Under Article 44 of the Dutch traffic code, motorised traffic in a woonerf or "recreation area" is restricted to walking pace.

The term "woonerf" has been adopted directly by some English-language publications. In the UK, these areas are called home zones.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Home_zone

Comment: Many thanks! Just what I was looking for.

Comment: 'Shared space' is becoming more common.

Answer (score 1):

We don't really have a word for this beyond *shared roadway*.

Most typically you'd see a sign that says:

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Generically, it would be a [***multipurpose***](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/multipurpose) *road*:

> [Merriam-Webster]
>   : serving or able to serve more than one purpose
>   // a *multipurpose* tool
>   // *multipurpose* rooms
>   // a *multi-purpose* cleaner

In other words, the road serves more than one purpose: it accommodates (was designed for) cars and it also accommodates pedestrian.